# LinkedIn login screen is in zh_CN but phone is in zh_TW

Tags: android, linkedin-api

Android multilingual support:

The phone locale is set to Traditional Chinese (zh_TW or zh_HK) but the WebView OAuth login displays Simplified Chinese (zh_CN).

It seems to be able to detect Chinese from English but not Traditional from Simplified.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The website is available in both 正體中文 (traditional) and 简体中文 (simplified), maybe first check that your locale is Taiwan. I have the same problem, my account language in the website is set to English, still it shows me the login page in the oauth in the android app in spanish (I'm mexican). Even if I change the language of the APP to english, portuguese, italian, french, chinese, it still shows me the login in spanish.
I guess it's a bug in their API and they are showing you the locale based in your geographical location. If you are in Taiwan and still don't see traditional chinese, it might be because they are considering Taiwan part of china (wtf?)

Comment: Physical location is in Taiwan, but LinkedIn should not know because location isn't shared before login. They should be able to detect locale.

Comment: Yes but remember all requests have an IP and from there they can still detect your physical location. I hope they solve this soon. Kind regards!